# Unity odd error [9:14:44] any ideas on what it could be?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Error Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBhuw.png)

Unity version: 2019.2.14f1
Visual studio: 16.3.9

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Unity & resetting factory settings.

It may be due to unity's internal compiler or the assets installed.

If you have any further information on what it could be please reply.

Comment: Those numbers, by the way, are a time stamp.

Comment: Clear and forget. Unless it comes back or stops from building it’s just editor error and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer lies here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1680858/blank-console-error-on-empty-project-with-a-single.html

Go to "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.14f1\Editor\Data\Tools\RoslynScripts"

Edit "unity_csc.bat"

Replace the line that says "%APPLICATION_CONTENTS%\Tools\Roslyn\csc" /shared % with the following: "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.14f1\Editor\Data\Tools\Roslyn\csc.exe" /shared %

Reopen the same project in Unity and it should work.